# Is strncpy secure for iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, c++, string, printf

Is `strncpy()` secure for iPhone development?

If not, what is a better String API to use that is recommended to be secure?

Comment: it would be more helpful if you specified more context...what are you trying to copy, why does it need to be secure, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the limitations of `strncpy()`, then it is OK.  I avoid it because I don't like its limitations, which are two-fold:

- It does not guarantee null termination
- It always writes to every byte of the target buffer

This means that if you write:

```
char little[10];
char large[20480];

strncpy(little, sizeof(little), "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
strncpy(large,  sizeof(large),  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
```

Then `little` is not a null-terminated string, though no buffer overflow has occurred, and large had 20454 nulls copied to its tail end.  Both are troublesome.

- Consider whether `strlcpy()` and `strlcat()` are available on iOS; they are on Mac OS X.

If you're coding in C++, you shouldn't be using C strings at all, or only in the most limited circumstances where a system service requires the use, and then you should have a cover function (inline) that takes a C++ string and passes the `somestring.c_str()` value to the system service.

If you're coding in Objective-C, you'll use the NS* strings.

So, only consider `strncpy()` if you are coding in C.  Treat it with caution even so.

I have a thesis (and I don't lay any claim to novelty in it — I collected the idea from others):

- You can only use functions like `strcpy()`, `strncpy()`, `strcat()` and `strncat()` safely if you know the lengths of the strings, both the target buffers and the source strings (and you know the foibles of the function you're calling — quickly, what does the length passed to `strncat()` represent?<sup>(1)</sup>).
- If you know how long everything is, you don't need to use functions like `strcpy()`; you can use `memmove()` (or `memcpy()`).
- So the string copy and move functions should be irrelevant; you don't need them in safe code because you know how long everything is and can therefore use the memory routines instead.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The length is the space available in the target buffer after the current string is accounted for.  So, to be able to use `strncat()`, you must know how long the string is in the target string, and the total length available, so that you can have `strncat()` skip over the initial segment of the string and then concatenate some or all of the second string.  But, if you know that, you could have used:

```
strncpy(target + curr_target_strlen, source, target_size - curr_target_strlen);
```

which would be 'more efficient' because it doesn't involve skipping over the leading part of the string (which, incidentally, can lead to quadratic behaviour if you're building a long string with lots of `strncat()` or `strcat()` operations).  Or, given that you know all the sizes, you could use `memmove()`:

```
size_t copy_length = target_size - curr_target_strlen;
if (copy_length > source_strlen)
    copy_length = source_strlen + 1;
memmove(target + curr_target_strlen, source, copy_length);
```

And, unless I've got an off-by-one error in code written on the spur of the moment, that avoids most of the problems with `strncat()`.  If you always use `strncat()` with the first argument pointing to the null at the end of a string, it has its uses (and may be optimized in assembler.  Otherwise, it is not a good choice — IMNSHO.

Answer (score 0):

Specify what you mean for secure, in any case `strncpy` on iPhone is as secure as it would be on every other platform.

Since you need `strncpy` I guess you are not working with `NSString`s so I don't see any problem in using it.